# How to delete an existing object and make a new one in java?

Tags: java, object

I want to delete a previous object of my class created in an other class and make a new one after it.

Here are part of my code:

```
//DataBase
DataBase data_base;
Document financial_document;

/**
 * Creates new form FinancialDocumentsJFrame
 */ 
public FinancialDocumentsJFrame() {

    frameWidth = this.getWidth();
    frameHeight = this.getHeight();

    panelWidth = frameWidth;
    panelHeight = frameHeight;

    data_base = new DataBase();

    code_table_hashmap = data_base.code_table;
    activity_table_hashmap = data_base.activity_table;
    client_table_hashmap = data_base.client_table;
    employee_table_hashmap = data_base.employee_table;

    initComponents();
    // Sets size of the frame.
    if(false) // Full screen mode
    {
        // Disables decorations for this frame.
        //this.setUndecorated(true);
        // Puts the frame to full screen.
        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    else // Window mode
    {
        // Size of the frame.
        this.setSize(1100, 800);
        // Puts frame to center of the screen.
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // So that frame cannot be resizable by the user.
        this.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

I have declaration of the object before my class and made a new object in one method of my class.

Now I need to delete this object in another method and make a new one.

Here are my codes:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (bill_documentType==1){
        fd_document_type = true;
    } 
    else if (bill_documentType==0){
        fd_document_type = false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error in Document Type!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (bill_documentStatus==1){
        fd_document_status = true;
    } 
    else if (bill_documentStatus==0){
        fd_document_status = false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error in Document Status!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (jTextField1.getText().equals("") || jTextField2.getText().equals("") || jTextField3.getText().equals("")|| jTextField4.getText().equals("")|| jTextField5.getText().equals("")|| bill_documentStatus==-1){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "لطفا همه فيلد ها را پر كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (jTextField1.getText().length()!=7 || jTextField2.getText().length()!=10 || jTextField3.getText().length()>10 || jTextField5.getText().length()>10) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentNumberText(jTextField1.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره سند نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (!checkDocumentDateText(jTextField2.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي تارخ سند نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (!checkDocumentClientNumberText(jTextField3.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره مشتري نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentAmountText(jTextField4.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي مبلغ نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentEmployeeNumberText(jTextField5.getText())) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره پرسنلي نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentEmployeeNumberExistence(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField5.getText())) || !checkDocumentClientNumberExistence(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField3.getText()))){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره مشتري يا شماره پرسنلي ناموجود است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==-1){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "كد معين انتخاب نشده است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==-1 && jTextField6.getText().equals("") ){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "شرح انتخاب نشده است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        boolean exists = data_base.selectQueryCheckDocument("Select * From document;",Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField1.getText()), fd_document_type, fd_document_status, jTextField2.getText(), Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        if (exists) { 
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي موجود است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } 
        else {
            jButton2.setEnabled(true);
            jButton3.setEnabled(true);
            jTextField1.setEnabled(false);
            jTextField2.setEnabled(false);
            jTextField3.setEnabled(false); 
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);

            fd_document_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField1.getText()); 
            fd_document_date = jTextField2.getText();
            fd_document_statement = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            fd_document_code_number = getCodeNumber(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            fd_document_employee_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField5.getText());
            fd_document_client_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField3.getText());
            document_amount = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField4.getText());

***here is the object creation:  financial_document = new Document(fd_document_number, fd_document_type, fd_document_status, fd_document_date, fd_document_statement, fd_document_code_number, fd_document_employee_number, fd_document_client_number, document_amount);
            financial_document.printDocumentInformation();

    }

    } 
}
```

Now the next method which I need to delete the object and make new one:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
*** deleting: financial_document = null;
    if (bill_documentType==1){
        fd_document_type = true;
    } 
    else if (bill_documentType==0){
        fd_document_type = false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error in Document Type!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (bill_documentStatus==1){
        fd_document_status = true;
    } 
    else if (bill_documentStatus==0){
        fd_document_status = false;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error in Document Status!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (jTextField4.getText().equals("")|| jTextField5.getText().equals("")|| bill_documentStatus==-1){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "لطفا همه فيلد ها را پر كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentAmountText(jTextField4.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي مبلغ نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentEmployeeNumberText(jTextField5.getText())) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره پرسنلي نامعتبر است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } 
    else if (!checkDocumentEmployeeNumberExistence(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField5.getText())) || !checkDocumentClientNumberExistence(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField3.getText()))){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي شماره مشتري يا شماره پرسنلي ناموجود است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==-1){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "كد معين انتخاب نشده است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==-1 && jTextField6.getText().equals("") ){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "شرح انتخاب نشده است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        boolean exists = data_base.selectQueryCheckDocument("Select * From document;",Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField1.getText()), fd_document_type, fd_document_status, jTextField2.getText(), Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        if (exists) { 
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "ورودي موجود است لطفا دوباره بررسي كنيد", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } 
        else {

            fd_document_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField1.getText()); 
            fd_document_date = jTextField2.getText();
            fd_document_statement = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            fd_document_code_number = getCodeNumber(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            fd_document_employee_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField5.getText());
            fd_document_client_number = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField3.getText());
            document_amount = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(jTextField4.getText());



***New object creation:            financial_document = new Document(fd_document_number, fd_document_type, fd_document_status, fd_document_date, fd_document_statement, fd_document_code_number, fd_document_employee_number, fd_document_client_number, document_amount);
            financial_document.printDocumentInformation();
    }
    }

}
```

I want to know if **financial_document = null;** dose the trick and the code will work properly.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this deleting and creating?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `financial_document = null` then, provided there are no other references to it in your application, it will be deleted from memory during the next "garbage collection". Until the next garbage collection, it is essentially deleted but in theory you could still access it by dumping the memory of the machine the app is running on. You could help prevent there being other references to it by making the field `private` instead of the default access specifier.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this deleting and creating?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so much about creating/deleting objects, but to ask yourself: "Who knows this object?".

If you you do...

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
```

...then you create a new object of type "MyClass" and store a reference to it in the variable x. So, whatever x is defined in, it "knows" your newly created MyClass object. If you now do...

```
x = null;
```

...then this reference to the "old" MyClass object will be "forgotten" / overwritten with `null`. If you didn't pass x somewhere else, no other object will "know" x and thus x is effectivly "lost" and will be completely removed from memory by the garbage collector.

Same thing is you overwrite x:

```
x = new MyClass();
```

Again, your old object that you stored in "x" before that will be "forgotten".

<s>As your code doesn't work since you declare `financial_document` outside of your class, it's hard to guess if it works, but if you replace the reference to your old document with a new one, in theory, that should effectively be "deleting" your old object from memory, yes.</s>

Edit: As you are removing the reference to your financial_document, it should effectively be "deleting" your old object from memory, yes, unless of course you have passed it to the outside in the mean time.

Comment: I think the financial_document is a field on the class - they just haven't posted the whole class, only snippets inside it.

Comment: Ah, you're right, my fault, it's just outside the constructor, not outside the class. I did misread that.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this deleting and creating?